# How to do `--index` with `git stash pop` by default?

Tags: configuration, git

`git stash pop` has an option `--index` which will try to restore the git index upon pop. How to use it by default? I want `git stash pop` to restore index by default.

Comment: P.S. I know I can create a bash alias like `git-stash-pop='git stash pop --index'`, but that feels too hacky. Any alternatives?